# Use of undeclared identifier 'NSLineBreakByWordWrapping' using xCode 4.3.3

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4.3, font-size

I get "Use of undeclared identifier 'NSLineBreakByWordWrapping'" on xCode 4.3.3 which doesn't appear on the beta one.

It happens on this code:

```
[text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:textConstraintRect.size lineBreakMode: NSLineBreakByWordWrapping].height);
```

What do I need to import to solve this one?

Please help,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `UILineBreakModeWordWrap` instead.

Comment: facing the same problem in xcode 4.2 ...use of undeclared identifier nslinebreakbywordwrapping    in my CCImage.mm

Answer (score 9):

Or   `NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping` in swift

Comment: Swift in Xcode 4.3.3? Why did you bump this old question?

Comment: NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping in Swift 4.0